# How do I log into a site externally?

Tags: javascript, html, roblox

To be more specific, I'm trying to make a webpage that tries to log into roblox.com from out of the site. i have the username and password forms, plus a submit button, but i'm not really sure where to go from here.

Comment: Simply, you cannot. (well, unless they provide you with an API to do so)

Comment: If your target website login form includes a special login anti-CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) token, then you might need to extract this token first - which, if it can be done Client-side - would be a security vulnerability, and if done server-side would not allow you to transfer the received authorisation cookies to the client.

Comment: @le_m you comment seems more appropriate to point `2)` of Webeng's answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question depends on what exactly you mean by logging into a site externally.

**1)** if you mean having a "guest" website within a "host" website, and having that "host" website do the logging in and controlling the website, then you will have big issues with the **Same Origin Policy**:

> The same-origin policy restricts how a document or script loaded from
>   one origin can interact with a resource from another origin. It is a
>   critical security mechanism for isolating potentially malicious
>   documents.

**2)** If you meant just the process of logging in, and being redirected to the site you're logging into, it might be possible depending on the "guest" site you're logging in to. What you have to check is the `<form>` that is being submitted in the "guest" site and see if you can mimic the https request being sent from your "host" site.

Comment: If someone disagrees with what I said, please point out what you disagree with. I have no emotional attachment to the outcome, just looking for a logical discussion.

Comment: op mentioned specific site ...which has an extensive api. Not sure how a generic answer helps

Comment: I see @charlietfl. I'm not very familiar with roblox.com so I wasn't aware there is an API for this done by the site (the OP didn't mention an API in his question). My understanding of the question was that the OP wanted to know how to get the process of logging into a website from another website, though since he didn't specify much more than that, I gave a general answer since I wasn't sure what he wanted. My understanding could however be wrong and I thank you for your input.